# Subquery error message while running query

Tags: sql, subquery

```
UPDATE rm 
SET rm.cost_sqft = ISNULL((SELECT 
                               CASE 
                                  WHEN (rm.rm_cat IN ('8','NON-REPORT') AND rm.space_fee = 'No') 
                                     THEN '0' 
                                     ELSE rent_w.w * @rental_rate 
                               END
                           FROM 
                               @rental_weight AS rent_w, bl, rm          
                           WHERE 
                               rm.main_contact = rent_w.space_type
                               AND rm.description = rent_w.space_quality
                               AND bl.cost_type = rent_w.campuse_cost       
                               AND bl.bl_id = rm.bl_id),'0') 
WHERE rm.bl_id = @bl_id
  AND rm.fl_id = @fl_id
  AND rm.rm_id = @rm_id
```

While running this statement, I get this error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure icat_rm_cost_sqft, Line 100 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: What part of the message do you not understand?  Your query has one subquery and the message seems clear.

Comment: whats wrong in the code> why am I getting this error message?

Comment: This question would be easier to read if you started with a bit of an introduction. Please see
[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](http://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins.aspx) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the subquery (the select) is returning more than one row for a given key to be applied to the update.

Consider the scenario where the update becomes something like this very contrived scenario:

Sample data in a table called Customer:

```
cust_id   cust_type     name
1          X            Fred
1          Y            jack
```

And the query which will generate the error:

```sql
update customer
    set name = (
           select "MR " || name
           from customer
           where cust_id = 1 /* returns Fred and Jack */
        )
    where cust_id = 1 and cust_type = 'X';
```

What name should customer 1X be updated to? "Mr Fred" or "Mr Jack"? the RDBMS can't decide for you, you need to modify the query as a correlated subquery (add a join condition on cust_type) or a subquery that just returns one row.

Granted the above is very contrived, but that is what the error is telling you.

Comment: @Abhilasha_Joshi if this has helped you, could you please accept the answer (click on the grey check mark next to the answer) and up vote it? Thanks.